# Is the Borel subgroup the only closed double coset?

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a quasisplit connected reductive group over a $p$-adic field $k$.  Identify $G$ with its rational points.  Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$ containing a maximal torus $T$, both defined over $k$.  For $w \in N_G(T)$, consider the double cosets $BwB$, which are locally closed submanifolds of $G$.  Is $B$ the only closed double coset?  Is there some general description of the closure of a Bruhat cell?

Comment: For the final question over any field equipped with a non-trivial absolute value (or even a wider class of Hausdorff topological fields), see 21.28 in Borel's *Linear Algebraic Groups* (2nd ed.).

Comment: @D_S: Your first line is confusing to me, since it's misleading to *identify* an algebraic group with its points over a field which isn't algebraically closed.      The group scheme formulation is generally preferable in any case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, and this holds for algebraically closed field as well as local field of charracteristic 0, at least in the split case, the description of orbit closures is as follows: 
Let $\omega \in W_G$ be a weyl element, and write $\omega = \sigma_{\alpha_1} ... \sigma_{\alpha_k}$ as a reduced expression in simple reflections, i.e. 
$\ell(\omega) = k$. 
Let $P_{\alpha_i}$ denote the parabolic subgroup containing $T$ of the form 
$SL_2^\alpha B$ where $SL_2^\alpha$ is the $SL_2$-triple with roots 
$\alpha, -\alpha$. Then, the orbit closure is given by
$\overline{B \omega B} = P_{\alpha_1} ... P_{\alpha_k}B$. In particular, 
$B$ is the unique closed orbit, and the orbit closure contains exactly those orbits $B \omega' B$ such that $\omega'$ is obtained from $\omega$ by excising several reflections from the reduced expression.

Comment: As mentioned to me by Uri Bader, the order I described in my answer on the $\omega$-s is called Bruhat order https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_order

Comment: Note that the question is formulated in the quasisplit (not the split) case.  (Also, I think your "arising" should be something like "excising".)

Comment: thanks, I edited my answer. For some reason I assumed that the torus in the problem is split.